# Distill bert and svm for text classification

Tags: nlp, torch, word-embedding

I am using DistillBert from hugging face to get the vector embedding of the words. The output for the example in hugging face will be a torch tensor with three dimensions. how can I feed these embeddings to an SVM?
I did detach the vectors and then reshape them to be 2 dimensional as an input for SVM. I was wondering if it is right?
So here, I have a list of sentences. I will make a for loop and get the vectors.
Code:
'''

```
embeddings=[]
embedding_np_array=[]
for i in my_list:
   tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')
   model = DistilBertModel.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')
   input_ids = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode("Hello, my dog is cute")).unsqueeze(0)
   outputs = model(input_ids)
   last_hidden_states = outputs[0]
   embeddings.append(last_hidden_states)

for i in embeddings:
     embedding_np_array.append(i.detach().numpy())
input_svm=embedding_np_array.reshape(embedding_np_array.reshape[0],-1)
```

'''